# Group array with a given id in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, group-by

I pass an array and an id to a function, this function will group that array by id.

```
id = "f58d5d3a6c4"; // id is read-only
array = [
    {createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:13.915", message: "Hello Subscriber"},
    {createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:42.462", message: "New Messages"},
    {createOn: "2021-01-29T14:21:01.761", message: "Hello"},
    {createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02:56.145", message: "Hello Subscriber"}
]
```

I want to group the above array like so:

```
"f58d5d3a6c4": [
    {createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:13.915", message: "Hello Subscriber"},
    {createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:42.462", message: "New Messages"},
    {createOn: "2021-01-29T14:21:01.761", message: "Hello"},
    {createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02:56.145", message: "Hello Subscriber"}
]
```

This is my code, but I just get an empty array after console.log it out:

```
const group = array.reduce((r, a) => {
    var key = id;
    key = [...(r || []), a];
    return r;
}, []);
```

Can you help me how to fix that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complicated, why not just

```js
id = "f58d5d3a6c4"; // id is read-only
array = [
    {createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:13.915", message: "Hello Subscriber"},
    {createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:42.462", message: "New Messages"},
    {createOn: "2021-01-29T14:21:01.761", message: "Hello"},
    {createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02:56.145", message: "Hello Subscriber"}
]


const newObj = {
  [id]: array
};
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Oh. Perhaps I thought it was too complicated. :))
Thank you

Comment: But what if I want to return an array? like `["f58d5d3a6c4": [....]]`

Comment: That syntax is not valid.